# order by select (sorting) from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to gwt r.QuestionId- sorted. but i get unsorted QuestionId althought i mentioned order by QuestionId ASC.

```
SELECT r.QuestionId,
       s.NAME AS Subject,
       d.value AS variant,
       r.Username,
       r.UserAnswer,
       r.Correctanswer,
       r.ExamTimeLine,
       r.Createtime
FROM resultlog r
INNER JOIN test_table t ON t.ID = r.QuestionId
INNER JOIN subject s ON s.ID= t.SUBJECT
INNER JOIN DICTIONARY d ON d.ID = t.Variant
WHERE r.Username LIKE 'Islam Ismayilov'
  AND r.Createtime > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
ORDER BY r.QuestionId ASC ;
```

result of code above mentioned code  :

[image]

Comment: Use correct data types; and see normalisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QuestionId` would appear to be a string, rather than a number.

One method converts the value to a number, using implicit conversion:

```
order by (r.QuestionId + 0) ASC
```

If the id looks like a number, you should probably declare it as a number.  This has several advantages:

- It works correctly with sorting.
- You can use `auto_increment` to automatically set a value.
- It always occupies 4 bytes, which is convenient for indexes and foreign key references.

Comment: thx a lot. it worked  as you worte : order by (r.QuestionId + 0) ASC